# How to keep original JSON format after deleting ID using PHP

Tags: php, json, string, format

I have a function to delete a PID inside a JSON string. This function works fine, but when I encode in JSON format the resulting string again (using `json_encode`) the original JSON format is lost.

How to keep this original format. That's the question. I need help to do it.

This is the code:

```
function deletePID($idToRemove, $dataBase) {
    if (!empty($dataBase)) {
        $dataArray = json_decode($dataBase, true);
        if (is_array($dataArray)) {
            if (is_numeric($idToRemove)) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataArray['cP']); $i++) {
                    $thisChannel = $dataArray['cP'][$i]['cID'];
                    if ($idToRemove == $thisChannel) {
                        unset($dataArray['cP'][$i]);
                    }
                }
                $thisJason = json_encode($dataArray);
                return $thisJason;
            }
        }
    }
}

$database = '{"cP":[{"cID":"1","PID":"30144"},{"cID":"2","PID":"30147"},{"cID":"3","PID":"30150"}]}';

$pidToDelete = 2;

echo deletePID($pidToDelete, $database);
```

Output is:

```
{"cP":{"0":{"cID":"1","PID":"30144"},"2":{"cID":"3","PID":"30150"}}}
```

Instead of:

```
{"cP":[{"cID":"1","PID":"30144"},{"cID":"3","PID":"30150"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have consecutive indexes for it to encode that way.  Use `array_values()` to re-index:

```
$thisJason = json_encode(array_values($dataArray));
```